# Iphone multiple images from uiimagepicker

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm developing an Iphone application where you select photos from your gallery and then make a new album, the problem it's that I am only getting 1 image at a time.

My problem it's that I need to select multiple images at a time or even the hole album.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo, Keep adding the selected images reference in an array, and make sure it doesn't call dismissModalViewController on selection.

Comment: how would you suggest exiting the modal, or displaying to the user that something was selected?

Comment: Although its an old answer, exit on - imagePickerControllerDidCancel: and have a max count, say, when 5 or 10 images are selected. Perhaps not the best user experience anymore, I suggest explore AssetsLibrary as well as how the following fellow is doing it: https://github.com/chiunam/CTAssetsPickerController